# Only fetch requests with 'GET' method work

Tags: .net, docker, kubernetes, next.js

I have a kubernetes cluster with a NextJS app and a dotnet service.
It's supposed to be a simple CRUD, but only get requests work.
I'm already accepting CORS in the dotnet service using app.UseCors and [EnableCors("*")]

Post requests stay forever loading
[DevTools network logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlHwK.png)

Put requests return 'NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI'
[DevTools network logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWDQK.png)

Delete requests return 'NS_BINDING_ABORTED'
[DevTools network logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r79SF.png)

But get requests work since I can see the list of products rendered in the page

```
kubectl get svc -A

NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                db-service                  ClusterIP   10.96.236.102   <none>        3306/TCP                 142m
default                front-service               NodePort    10.96.126.106   <none>        80:30100/TCP             142m
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  30d
default                produtos-service            ClusterIP   10.111.95.193   <none>        80/TCP                   142m
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   30d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.101.138.14   <none>        8000/TCP                 30d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.106.87.156   <none>        80/TCP                   30d
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: produtos-deployment
  labels:
    app: produtos
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: produtos
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: produtos
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: produtos
        image: wallysf/sorveteria-produtos:v1.0
        env:
        - name: DB_URL
          value: db-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: produtos-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: produtos
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-deployment
  labels:
    app: front
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: front
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front
        image: wallysf/sorveteria-front:v2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: URL_PRODUTOS
          value: produtos-service
        - name: PORT_PRODUTOS
          value: "80"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: front
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30100
```

Did some research and maybe the problem is that I'm trying to use fetch from the client-side, because I need to use it on button clicks. Seems like the correct way is to use an API Route handler. I'll try that when I have time available

Comment: WE need more info. Can you show us kubect get services?

Comment: @RichardRublev just added more info

Comment: Try to check all pods in front-service.

Comment: no errors on the logs, is running ok